# How can I log individual scalar values from a TensorFlow Variable?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

How can I log (with `SummaryWriter`, e.g. for [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html)) of individual scalar elements of a tensor [`Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable)? For example, how can I log individual weights of a given layer or node in a network?

In my example code, I've pressed a general feed-forward neural network into service to do simple linear regression, and want (in that case) to log the weights of the lone node in the lone hidden layer as learning progresses.

I can get these values explicitly during a session with, for example

```
sess.run(layer_weights)[0][i][0]
```

for the `i`-th weight, where `layer_weights` is a list of the weight `Variable`s; but I can't figure out how to log the corresponding scalar values. If I try

```
w1 = tf.slice(layer_weights[0], [0], [1])[0]
tf.scalar_summary('w1', w1)
```

or

```
w1 = layer_weights[0][1][0]
tf.scalar_summary('w1', w1)
```

I get

> ValueError: Shape (5, 1) must have rank 1

How can I log individual scalar values from a TensorFlow `Variable`?

---

```
from __future__ import (absolute_import, print_function, division, unicode_literals)

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# Basic model parameters as external flags
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('network_nodes', [5, 1], 'The number of nodes in each layer, including input and output.')
flags.DEFINE_float('epochs', 250, 'Epochs to run')
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.15, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', './data', 'Directory to hold training and test data.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', './_tmp/train', 'Directory to log training (and the network def).')
flags.DEFINE_string('test_dir', './_tmp/test', 'Directory to log testing.')


def variable_summaries(var, name):
    with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
        mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
        tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)
        with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
            stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var - mean)))
            tf.scalar_summary('sttdev/' + name, stddev)
    tf.scalar_summary('max/' + name, tf.reduce_max(var))
    tf.scalar_summary('min/' + name, tf.reduce_min(var))
    tf.histogram_summary(name, var)


def add_layer(input_tensor, input_dim, output_dim, neuron_fn, layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
        with tf.name_scope("weights"):
            weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([input_dim, output_dim], stddev=0.1))
        with tf.name_scope("biases"):
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[output_dim]))
        with tf.name_scope('activations'):
            with tf.name_scope('weighted_inputs'):
                weighted_inputs = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases
                tf.histogram_summary(layer_name + '/weighted_inputs', weighted_inputs)
            output = neuron_fn(weighted_inputs)
    return output, weights, biases


def make_ff_network(nodes, input_activation, hidden_activation_fn=tf.nn.sigmoid, output_activation_fn=tf.nn.softmax):
    layer_activations = [input_activation]
    layer_weights = []
    layer_biases = []
    n_layers = len(nodes)
    for l in range(1, n_layers):
        a, w, b = add_layer(layer_activations[l - 1], nodes[l - 1], nodes[l],
                         output_activation_fn if l == n_layers - 1 else hidden_activation_fn,
                         'output_layer' if l == n_layers - 1 else 'hidden_layer' + (
                             '_{}'.format(l) if n_layers > 3 else ''))
        layer_activations += [a]
        layer_weights += [w]
        layer_biases += [b]
    with tf.name_scope('output'):
        net_activation = tf.identity(layer_activations[-1], name='network_activation')
    return net_activation, layer_weights, layer_biases

# Inputs and outputs
with tf.name_scope('data'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, FLAGS.network_nodes[0]], name='inputs')
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, FLAGS.network_nodes[-1]], name='correct_outputs')

# Network structure
y, layer_weights, layer_biases = make_ff_network(FLAGS.network_nodes, x, output_activation_fn=tf.identity)

# Metrics and operations
with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_))
    # NONE OF THESE WORK:
    #w1 = tf.slice(layer_weights[0], [0], [1])[0]
    #tf.scalar_summary('w1', w1)
    #w1 = layer_weights[0][1][0]
    #tf.scalar_summary('w1', w1)
    tf.scalar_summary('loss', loss)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(loss)

# Logging
train_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, tf.get_default_graph())
test_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.test_dir)
merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()



W = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])

train_x = np.random.rand(100000, FLAGS.network_nodes[0])
train_y = np.array([np.dot(W, train_x.T)+ 6.0]).T

test_x = np.random.rand(1000, FLAGS.network_nodes[0])
test_y = np.array([np.dot(W, test_x.T)+ 6.0]).T

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    for ep in range(FLAGS.epochs):
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: train_x, y_: train_y})
        summary = sess.run(merged, feed_dict={x: test_x, y_: test_y})
        test_writer.add_summary(summary, ep+1)

    # THESE WORK
    print('w1 = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_weights)[0][0][0]))
    print('w2 = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_weights)[0][1][0]))
    print('w3 = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_weights)[0][2][0]))
    print('w4 = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_weights)[0][3][0]))
    print('w5 = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_weights)[0][4][0]))
    print(' b = {}'.format(sess.run(layer_biases)[0][0]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different errors in the code.

The main problem is that you are passing a python list of tensors to the scalar_summary.
The error says that your are passing a tensor that does not have Rank 1 is related to the slice operation.

You want to pass the weights and log them layer per layer. One way to do that is to log each weight on each layer:

```
for weight in layer_weights:
    tf.scalar_summary([ ['%s_w%d%d' % (weight.name, i,j) for i in xrange(len(layer_weights))]  for j in xrange(5) ], weight)
```

This will produce in tensorboard `tensorboard --logdir=./_tmp/test` these nice  graphs

[image]